# wiered javascript result in my code undefiend variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var cache = new Array();
    $("#selectOne").change(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();

        if (cache[val] == null) {
           // do something
         }
      });
   });
```

the if line is giving me that error :

```
Error: TypeError: cache[val] is undefined
```

can anyone tell me why this error is raised ?

Comment: You are trying to call element with index of val in cache array. But your array is empty, so this way you get your error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cache[val]` is not defined.
Try this instead:

```
if(typeof cache[val] == 'undefined') {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (cache[val] == null) {
      // do something
}
```

above is giving you correct error because you did not added any array element yet so if condition will throw undefined error.

You should also add `&& typeof cache[val] == 'undefined'` too

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
if (typeof cache[val] == 'undefined') {
  // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `cache` value is initialized, but doesn't hold any values.
Therefore `cache[val]` doesn't exist, because your array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps since the index does not exists it returns undefined?

You should first check if the index of the array "cache" exists:

```
if (typeof(cache[val] != 'undefined')) {
    if (cache[val] == null) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you pass integer while traversing the array i.e. in `cache[val]` make sure that `val` is integer